# TikZ externalisation in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-external

I want to use the TikZ externalization feature in my beamer document. Works fine, but when I use something like

```
path<1->[draw] (0,0) -- (0,1);
path<2->[draw] (0,0) -- (1,0);
```

… only the picture of the first frame will be externalized. Is there any way to fix that? I read the externalization part of the official documentation, but beamer is not mentioned anywhere and I am not sure I understand the “limitation” parts.

Comment: I suppose you need to write <1-10> (or whatever is the maximum step size) to your entire `tikzpicture` (perhaps by means of `\only<1-10>{\begin{tikzpicture} .... \end{tikzpicture}}` ?)

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger: Works well, thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, here is an answer: The main idea is to use `\only<1-10>{\begin{tikzpicture} .... \end{tikzpicture}}` (if you got 10 figures).

However then the numbering makes some problems. In [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154041/how-to-reset-tikzs-externalization-counter) I asked how to fix that: Before each new set of figures I use `\settikzdir{foo}` to set another directory for my figures and reset the number. The command:

```
\tikzset{external/figure name = figure}
\newcommand{\settikzdir}[1]{
  \tikzset{external/reset counter = figure}
  But\tikzsetexternalprefix{./tikz/#1/}
}
```

Works  fine here. :)